# Mac convert .xvid to .vob?

Tags: macos, mac, video, xvid, vob

I'm looking to burn a bunch of .xvid files so that they will play in a (very old) dvd player. Ideally, I would like to use as few discs as necessary. I assume that I will need two programs.

1) One that can convert .xvid files to .vob files

2) One that can burn these to DVD

Ideally, both of these would be freeware and compatible with Snow Leopard.

Comment: Nero does all you want, though not free (unless you look in the "right places").

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-mac.html). It's free, and I've yet to meet a conversion it couldn't do. It seems you have to install DivX and the Xvid codec seperately, but I presume you've done that already to get the files to play on your Mac.

I'm not so sure about burning to DVD, but will iDVD not do it?